# React onClick routing ONLY works SOMETIMES

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mantine

Here is the video proof.
https://dsc.cloud/leonardchoo/Screen-Recording-2022-03-08-at-17.25.58.mov

I'm running into a mysterious error where I click the button for navigation, "onClick" event is fired but it does not redirect and render the target component.

As you can see in the screenshot, the `onClick` event is logged, but the redirect does not happen.

I reproduced the situation here in [CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-stitch-wog1o6?file=/src/WrapperPage.tsx)

Stack

- React TS
- Mantine UI
- React Router V5

How can I solve this issue?

[image: screenshotError]

Comment: its working fine for me can you please mark it as closed If the issue is solved

Comment: Just checked on Codesandbox 22-3-8 17:21 JST. Still broken.

Comment: Your sandbox code appears to work just fine. I don't see any issue clicking the links. Is there something more specific you are doing that you haven't explained? Are there any errors? What are the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Ok, I think it finally reproed.... it seems to manifest if you click "quickly" between menu options.

Comment: @DrewReese That's what I did on the video, but what's annoying is that it often happens even when I'm very slow (first click in a while)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I noticed in your code was that is is rendering a `WrapperPage` component around each routed component with the navigation logic. I tried simplifying the `WrapperPage` code as much as possible.

Steps Taken:

1. Refactored the `header` and `navbar` props into standalone components in case there was issue generating JSX
2. Wrapped the `Switch` component in `App` with a single `WrapperPage` instead of each routed component

The issue persisted.

I next removed the `UnstyledButton` from `@mantine/core` so only the `Link` components were rendered, and could not reproduce. I then tried vanilla HTML buttons instead of the `UnstyledButton` and they again reproduced the issue.

So it seems it is an issue with rendering an interactive element (*i.e. anchor tag from `Link`*) within another interactive element (*i.e. `button` from `UnstyledButton`*) that is an issue. Swapping the element order, i.e. `Link` wrapping the `UnstyledButton`, appears to reduce the issue. I can't seem to reproduce the issue with the DOM structured this way.

Header

```
const CustomHeader = ({
  opened,
  setOpened
}: {
  opened: boolean;
  setOpened: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}) => {
  const theme = useMantineTheme();

  return (
    <Header height={70} padding="md">
      {/* Handle other responsive styles with MediaQuery component or createStyles function */}
      <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", height: "100%" }}>
        <MediaQuery largerThan="sm" styles={{ display: "none" }}>
          <Burger
            opened={opened}
            onClick={() => setOpened((o) => !o)}
            size="sm"
            color={theme.colors.gray[6]}
            mr="xl"
          />
        </MediaQuery>

        <Group>
          <ThemeIcon variant="light" color="orange">
            
          </ThemeIcon>
          <Text>Mantine AppShell with React Router</Text>
        </Group>
      </div>
    </Header>
  );
};
```

Navbar

```
const CustomNavbar = ({ opened }: { opened: boolean }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { classes } = useStyles();

  return (
    <Navbar
      padding="md"
      // Breakpoint at which navbar will be hidden if hidden prop is true
      hiddenBreakpoint="sm"
      // Hides navbar when viewport size is less than value specified in hiddenBreakpoint
      hidden={!opened}
      // when viewport size is less than theme.breakpoints.sm navbar width is 100%
      // viewport size > theme.breakpoints.sm – width is 300px
      // viewport size > theme.breakpoints.lg – width is 400px
      width={{ sm: 300, lg: 400 }}
    >
      <Link
        to="/dashboard"
        className={classes.link}
      >
        <UnstyledButton
          className={
            location.pathname === "/dashboard"
              ? classes.button_active
              : classes.button
          }
        >
          <Group>
            <ThemeIcon variant="light">
              <DashboardIcon />
            </ThemeIcon>
            <Text size="sm">Dashboard</Text>
          </Group>
        </UnstyledButton>
      </Link>
      <Link
        to="/new-recording"
        className={classes.link}
      >
        <UnstyledButton
          className={
            location.pathname === "/new-recording"
              ? classes.button_active
              : classes.button
          }
        >
          <Group>
            <ThemeIcon variant="light" color="red">
              <RadiobuttonIcon />
            </ThemeIcon>

            <Text size="sm">New Recording</Text>
          </Group>
        </UnstyledButton>
      </Link>
      <Link
        to="/calendar"
        className={classes.link}
      >
        <UnstyledButton
          className={
            location.pathname === "/calendar"
              ? classes.button_active
              : classes.button
          }
        >
          <Group>
            <ThemeIcon variant="light" color="orange">
              <CalendarIcon />
            </ThemeIcon>

            <Text size="sm">Calendar</Text>
          </Group>
        </UnstyledButton>
      </Link>
    </Navbar>
  );
};
```

WrapperPage

```
const WrapperPage = ({ children }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AppShell
      // navbarOffsetBreakpoint controls when navbar should no longer be offset with padding-left
      navbarOffsetBreakpoint="sm"
      // fixed prop on AppShell will be automatically added to Header and Navbar
      fixed
      header={<CustomHeader opened={opened} setOpened={setOpened} />}
      navbar={<CustomNavbar opened={opened} />}
    >
      {children}
    </AppShell>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-onclick-routing-only-works-sometimes]

Comment: Seems like this solved it! I did try swapping Link and UnstyledButton but perhaps I did something wrong that time. Also refactored WrapperPage as well. Thanks.